# Highmaps get lat/lon from a hc-key

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

Working with `highmaps` from `Highcharts`. I'm displaying a world map and trying to display some states like capitals using mappoint serie.

To display the states I need the lat/lon or the x/y coordinates. Is there any way to get the position based on the `hc-key` or the name of the state ?

Comment: For using latitude/longitude properties, look here: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/latlon. Also, here you can find an example where couple of cities are added using lat/lon: http://jsfiddle.net/tevxyeo8/.

Comment: I don't want to provide the coordinates by my self. the map will be generated dynamically so I need to get the coordinates by providing the hc-key or the name of the state or any other identifier.

Comment: Info about the latitude\longitude of a specific point can be found in the Point.properties object. Also, remember to read the 'ADD LAT/LON SUPPORT TO CUSTOM MAPS' section from https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/latlon if you are planning to use custom maps. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9gpc6zz3/.